# apply transparent background to divide plot area based on x values using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, scatter-plot, tidyverse

> I would appreciate any help to apply the transparent background colours below to
> divide into two parts the plot area based on x-values as illustrated in the plot below (vertical division).

**Here are my sample data and code:**

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)
```

**Here is the plot I would like to replicate, and the legend illustrates the change I want to implement:**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by transparent background. se in smooth lines?

Comment: I want to use the colours as in the example. Thanks, @PoGibas.

Comment: as in adding an alpha term? alpha controlls how transparent stuff is

Comment: What do you mean by "two parts the plot area based on x-values" and what's "vertical division"?

Comment: As illustrated by the legend of the sample plot. From 1990 to 2000 one background colour, and from 2000 to 2015 another colour.

Comment: I think there's confusion about what you want. The legend has 1990-2000 in blue, and 2000-2015 in red, which isn't reflected in the graph itself. Do you want one shaded area around a line, with some sort of 25-75% quartile area? And the shaded area colored based based on those two year groups?

Comment: That is the change I want to implement.

Comment: As illustrated by the legend of the sample plot,  want to plot one background colour from 1990 to 2000 and from 2000 to 2015 another colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this. You'll have to designate groups and fill by that group in your `geom_ribbon`, and set your `ymin` and `ymax` as you like.

```
library(tidyverse)
    mtcars$group <- ifelse(mtcars$wt <= 3.5, "<= 3.5", "> 3.5")
mtcars <- arrange(mtcars, wt)
mtcars$group2 <- rleid(mtcars$group)
mtcars_plot <- head(do.call(rbind, by(mtcars, mtcars$group2, rbind, NA)), -1)
mtcars_plot[,c("group2","group")] <- lapply(mtcars_plot[,c("group2","group")], na.locf)
mtcars_plot[] <- lapply(mtcars_plot, na.locf, fromLast = TRUE)

ggplot(mtcars_plot, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(), method=lm, se=F, fullrange=TRUE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = mpg *.75, ymax = mpg * 1.25, fill = group), alpha = .25) +
  labs(fill = "Weight Class")
```

[image]

**Edit**:

To map confidence intervals using `geom_ribbon` you'll have to calculate them  beforehand using `lm` and `predict`.

```
mtmodel <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
mtcars$Low <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,2]
mtcars$High <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,3]
```

Followed by the previous code to modify `mtcars`. Then plot with the calculated bounds.

```
ggplot(mtcars_plot, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(), method=lm, se=F, fullrange=TRUE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Low, ymax = High, fill = group), alpha = .25) +
  labs(fill = "Weight Class") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange"), name = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, @Anonymous coward. This solution is great and solves my problem.

Comment: Hi @Anonymous coward, I would appreciate your help to set the colours of the ribbon manually. Thanks for this great answer.

Comment: See my edits, you'll need to use `scale_fill_manual`. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, @Anonymous coward. Thank you very much for that. This is perfect.